# Angular-How can I disable options from one dropdown based on option selected on another dropdown?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I was working on a project with two drop-downs having grouped options and multiple selection [this is the stackblitz represntation](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-h4kuq8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts). There I was trying to disable the entire group of options selected in one dropdown, when it is selected in another dropdown.But I was facing a problem here.

Here is the JSON:

```
 items = [
    {
      type: 'all',
      name: ['All Pokemon'],
    },
    {
      type: 'water',
      name: [
        'Squirtle',
        'Wartortle',
        'Blastoise',
        'Psyduck',
        'Golduck',
        'Tentacool',
        'Seel',
      ],
    },
    {
      type: 'fire',
      name: [
        'Charmander',
        'Charizard',
        'Vulpix',
        'Arcanine',
        'Ponyta',
        'Magmar',
        'Cyndaquil',
      ],
    },
    {
      type: 'earth',
      name: ['Growlithe', 'Arcanine', 'Geodude', 'Golem', 'Onix'],
    },
  ];
```

When I select `Wartortle` from `type:water` in the 1st dropdown, the whole group of `type:water` should get disabled in the 2nd dropdown and in the 1st dropdown only the group of type:water should remain enabled..

This is what I was able to do so far:

I made two arrays(for 2 dropdowns):

```
this.items.forEach((data) => {
      data['disable'] = false;
    });
this.arr1 = this.items;
this.arr2 = this.items.filter((x) => x.type !== 'all');
```

This is the logic I am using to disbale it:

```
if (includeTest.length) {
      includeTest.map((x1) => {
        this.arr1.forEach((y1) => {
          if (y1.name.includes(x1)) {
            y1.disable = true;
          } else {
            y1.disable = false;
          }
        });
        this.arr2.forEach((y2) => {
          if (y2.name.includes(x1)) {
            y2.disable = true;
          } else {
            y2.disable = false;
          }
        });
      });
    } else {
      this.arr1.forEach((x) => {
        x.disable = false;
      });
      this.arr1.forEach((x) => {
        x.disable = false;
      });
    }
```

Here, `includeTest` contains array of string based on which,I have to filter out/disable the option groups.

Comment: Could you add an example of the behaviour like: select squirtle, then x are disable and y are enabled in dropdown 1, alfa are disbled and beta are enabled in dropdown 2. 
Your explanation of what you are trying to achieve is rather confusing.

Comment: @IDK4real I have added more details in the question.Regarding the 2nd point,take it this way, when a user selects an option from a group in the 1st dropdown then only that group is allowed to get disabled from the 2nd dropdown. Since there is mutiple selection, the user should not be allowed to select from different groups in the 1st dropdown at the same time and if they attempt to, then both dropdowns should reset when there is a change of group in the 1st dropdown.

Comment: The stackblitz seems to work just fine. What is missing, what is not working as desired?

Comment: @user776686 Like I said,When I select `Wartortle` from `type:water` in the 1st dropdown, the whole group of `type:water` should get disabled in the 2nd dropdown and in the 1st dropdown only the  group of `type:water` should remain enabled. In the stackblitz,  the 2nd condition is working fine but I am unable to disable the selected group in the 2nd dropdown.

Comment: The first condition seems just to be reversed. Meaning: when I select Wartotle in the first menu, then the water group remains enabled, but all other disabled in the second menu. Maybe it is just a trivial boolean inversion :)

Comment: @user776686 what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try to read about Angular Pipes, especially about "filter". There is lot's of resource in here and also in documentation of Angular.

Shortly described, all your 'ngFor' or 'ng-repeat' must be filtered through your filter pipe. When you select something from dropdown 1, the filter on dropdown 2, fill show data filtered based on dropdown 1 value or vice-versa.

```
if (dropdown1.type == 'water') {dropdown2.items = ...}
```

or

```
if (dropdown1.type == 'water' && dropdown1.name == 'Vulpix') {dropdown2.items = ...}
```

or

```
<li *ngFor="let item of dropdown2 | callback: filterData">...</li>

filterData(item: Item) {
    if (dropdown1.type == 'water' && item == 'your rules') {return item}
}
```

so the data of dropdown 2 always will be based on dropdown 1

Comment: Given that the primary goal is to disable, the filter pipe fails to achieve the desired goal.

Comment: disabled(or removed) as mentioned author... items can be marked for disabling in 'Controller', and block them for usage in 'View' regarding disabling method... it can be used in many ways, but the main thing is to filter || disable || remove || mark dropdown2 items based on dropdown1

can be used -> [attr.disabled] in Angular or 'ng-disabled' in AngularJS or any other method...

Comment: @TigranMakaryan I was able to achieve the disabling [of group of options here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-h4kuq8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).  But I am facing two problems here:
1. after disabling I am unable to enable the group
2. selection of options from two different groups should be possible,if one does try then both the dropdowns should get reset. How can I do it?

Comment: @user18067747  There is two things left to do... [See here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zktxwf?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

1) in app.component.html -> add (click) event on selectable items, by sending item itself

2) in app.component.ts -> add handler for that (click) event, and implement any logic that you need, Reset || Disable || Remove....

so you can always handle your click logic based on "item.disable" true || false

Comment: @TigranMakaryan I was able to enable/disable options. But another case arised, when I select `all` option, all the options from only the first dropdown should get disabled and enabled accordingly(none of the options from the 2nd dropdown should get disabled). So far, when I select the `all` option,all options from both the dropdown gets disabled. See [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-h4kuq8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)